# how can I have an $emit and a event bus in the same method?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

this code below, just fire the $emit and not the eventbus...

**component-b.js**

```
methods: {
    prevPage () {
      this.$emit('prevPage')
      eventBus.$emit('prevPage')
    },
}
```

[image]

are they anyway that I can fire boths events ?

Comment: i suggest to set ` eventBus.$emit('prevPage')` in the component a inside of the method that handle @prevPage

Comment: but the problem is that It can't handle those two emit...if I moved to component-a the functionality would be the same... it's weird that only fires the first emit and not the second...

Comment: please share some code snippet of your 3 components, i prefer to share it in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: check this working example https://codesandbox.io/s/j7vz9n9zn3

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim just added the code at https://codesandbox.io/s/484z3pxly7 ... but it's not working, I dont know if it is because I'm using axios...but if you download the project I think Ill be fine

Comment: check this https://codesandbox.io/s/m1o4j37n9